# 3d Graphing Data in matlab and changing the axis values

Tags: matlab

I am trying to do a 3d graph of a excel file that is 343 by 81 cells, The first column needs to be the X and the first row needs to be the Y and the remaining matrix needs to be the Z. I have the data successfully imported from excel and I create a matrix of the first column called energy (343,1)(x-axis), while creating a row matrix (1, 81) called Time Delay(y-axis) and a (343,81) matrix where the first column and row is zero called Absorbance Change(Z-axis). I've got the proper 3d graph that I need but I need the axes shown in the graph to be that of the Energy and Time Delay instead of the indices of the Absorbance Change matrix. I am putting the relevant portion of the code below as well as a picture of the graph:

```
EnergyString = dataArray{:, 1};
EnergyString(1,1) = {'0'};
Energy = str2double(EnergyString);
%Energy = [ Energy, zeros(343, 80) ];

TimeDelay = [ z1(1,1), z2(1,1), z3(1,1), z4(1,1), z5(1,1), z6(1,1), z7(1,1), z8(1,1), z9(1,1), z10(1,1), z11(1,1), z12(1,1), z13(1,1), z14(1,1), z15(1,1), z16(1,1), z17(1,1), z18(1,1), z19(1,1), z20(1,1), z21(1,1), z22(1,1), z23(1,1), z24(1,1), z25(1,1), z26(1,1), z27(1,1), z28(1,1), z29(1,1), z30(1,1), z31(1,1), z32(1,1), z33(1,1), z34(1,1), z35(1,1), z36(1,1), z37(1,1), z38(1,1), z39(1,1), z40(1,1), z41(1,1), z42(1,1), z42(1,1), z43(1,1), z44(1,1), z45(1,1), z46(1,1), z47(1,1), z48(1,1), z49(1,1), z50(1,1), z51(1,1), z52(1,1), z53(1,1), z54(1,1), z55(1,1), z56(1,1), z57(1,1), z58(1,1), z59(1,1), z60(1,1), z61(1,1), z62(1,1), z63(1,1), z64(1,1), z65(1,1), z66(1,1), z67(1,1), z68(1,1), z69(1,1), z70(1,1), z71(1,1), z72(1,1), z73(1,1), z74(1,1), z75(1,1), z76(1,1), z77(1,1), z78(1,1), z79(1,1), z80(1,1) ];
%TimeDelay = [ TimeDelay; zeros(342, 81)];

startRow formatSpec filename fileID delimiter ans EnergyString Alpha Beta Gamma Delta Epsilon Zeta Eta Theta Iota Kappa Lambda Mu Nu Xi Omicron Pi Rho Sigma Tau Upsilon Phi Chi Psi Omega AlphaAlpha AlphaBeta AlphaGamma AlphaDelta AlphaEpsilon AlphaZeta AlphaEta AlphaTheta AlphaIota AlphaKappa AlphaLambda AlphaMu AlphaNu AlphaXi AlphaOmicron AlphaPi AlphaRho AlphaSigma AlphaTau AlphaUpsilon AlphaPhi AlphaChi AlphaPsi AlphaOmega BetaAlpha BetaBeta BetaGamma BetaDelta BetaEpsilon BetaZeta BetaEta BetaTheta BetaIota BetaKappa BetaLambda BetaMu BetaNu BetaXi BetaOmicron BetaPi BetaRho BetaSigma BetaTau BetaUpsilon BetaPhi BetaChi BetaPsi BetaOmega GammaAlpha GammaBeta GammaGamma GammaDelta GammaEpsilon GammaZeta GammaEta GammaTheta; %Delete Excess Varaible

AbsorbanceChange = [ zeros(343, 1), z1, z2, z3, z4, z5, z6, z7, z8, z9, z10, z11, z12, z13, z14, z15, z16, z17, z18, z19, z20, z21, z22, z23, z24, z25, z26, z27, z28, z29, z30, z31, z32, z33, z34, z35, z36, z37, z38, z39, z40, z41, z42, z43, z44, z45, z46, z47, z48, z49, z50, z51, z52, z53, z54, z55, z56, z57, z58, z59, z60, z61, z62, z63, z64, z65, z66, z67, z68, z69, z70, z71, z72, z73, z74, z75, z76, z77, z78, z79, z80];
AbsorbanceChange(1,:) = 0;
clear  z1 z2 z3 z4 z5 z6 z7 z8 z9 z10 z11 z12 z13 z14 z15 z16 z17 z18 z19 z20 z21 z22 z23 z24 z25 z26 z27 z28 z29 z30 z31 z32 z33 z34 z35 z36 z37 z38 z39 z40 z41 z42 z43 z44 z45 z46 z47 z48 z49 z50 z51 z52 z53 z54 z55 z56 z57 z58 z59 z60 z61 z62 z63 z64 z65 z66 z67 z68 z69 z70  z71 z72 z73 z74 z75 z76 z77 z78 z79 z80; 


mesh(AbsorbanceChange) 
colorbar


title('WS2-Perovskite-image')
xlabel('Energy') % x-axis label
ylabel('Time-delay') % y-axis label
zlabel('Absorbance Change')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I type `help mesh` in MATLAB I see, among other thins, this:

> ```
> mesh(x,y,Z) and mesh(x,y,Z,C), with two vector arguments replacing
> the first two matrix arguments, must have length(x) = n and
> length(y) = m where [m,n] = size(Z).  In this case, the vertices
> of the mesh lines are the triples (x(j), y(i), Z(i,j)).
> Note that x corresponds to the columns of Z and y corresponds to
> the rows.
> ```

Thus, you can do

```
mesh(Energy, TimeDelay, AbsorbanceChange);
```

---

I don't know how you [read the data from file](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html), but there is a better way than specifying each cell individually in your code.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that tomorrow and let you know if it works.